# flutter shouldOverrideUrlLoading not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
  global.webViewController = controller;
  var url = navigationAction.request.url;
  if (!navigationAction.isForMainFrame && url != null && url.host == 'https://accounts.google.com/') {
    await controller.stopLoading();
  }

  if (url != null) {
    // 팝업이 열려있고, 목표 URL이 'dev.metapocket.io'인 경우 팝업 닫기
    if (isPopupOpened && url.host == 'dev.metapocket.io') {
      await controller.goBack();
      isPopupOpened = false;
      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
    }
    // 구글 로그인 사용자 설정 변경
    var googleOauth = 'https://accounts.google.com/';
    var myUrl = 'https://dev.metapocket.io/';
    print('before: $url.host');
    if (url.host.contains('accounts.google')) {
      print('after : $url.host');
      controller?.setOptions(options: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          userAgent: 'random',
            resourceCustomSchemes: ['intent']
        ),
      ));
      // 추가된 부분: WebView Controller 실행 여부 확인
      await controller?.reload();
    }
    if (url.host.contains('dev.metapocket.io') == myUrl) {
      // 추가된 부분: URL이 https://dev.metapocket.io/ 인 경우 Android User Agent로 변경
      controller?.setOptions(options: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
        crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
          userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 13; Build/UPP1.230113.010; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/120.0.6099.144 Mobile Safari/537.36',
            resourceCustomSchemes: ['intent']
        ),
      ));
      print('URL이 https://dev.metapocket.io/ 인 경우 Android User Agent로 변경됨.');
      // 여기에 추가: 특정 동작 수행 또는 추가적인 로직 적용
    }
    await controller?.reload();
  }
  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
},
```

My code is not working properly What is the problem? After changing the userAgent, I initialize the userAgent when it is in the existing domain again, and then an error appears that I can't find it when I go to the payment window

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.